# Vue.js sending email with SendGrid v3 : not allowed access

Tags: vue.js, sendgrid-api-v3

I am trying to send emails w SendGrid v3...
In development mode as I am sending msg from localhost and my SendGrid account is set up for my production domain www.mydomain.com, I get an error message : non authorized .. which I can understand...

```
Failed to load https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send: Response to preflight 
request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header 
has a value '://sendgrid.api-docs.io' that is not equal to the supplied origin. 
Origin '://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. Have the server send 
the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, 
set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Is there any way to use SendGrid in development mode ? or shoud I bypass sendingmail ?

```
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production) {
      this.sendContactEmail()
    } else {
      console.log('CANNOT SEND MESSAGE IN DEVELOPMENT ENVIRONMENT')
    }
```

thanks for feedback

Comment: CORS issue, I think you haven't purchased their services, so you can not send any email unless you sent email for free trial at their website (`The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header 
has a value '://sendgrid.api-docs.io'`).

Comment: I'll try to use Firebase function as a node/express server to perform the sendmail API call...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use SendGrid in a client-based application. That might be the reason why it is failing. You need a backend server/service, or as you told you can use firebase's serverless functions to trigger the API call